# VBA - Generación Excel desde Txt con VB.Net desde Programador de Tareas

Tags: excel, vba

tengo una aplicación en vba.net que genera un Excel a partir de un archivo plano (txt). El problema es que cuando ejecuto la aplicación para generar el Excel en interactivo funciona perfecto pero cuando lanzo la aplicación desde el Programador de Tareas me da un error "Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800AC472". Estoy ejecutándolo en un ordenador con windows 10 y Office Hogar y Empresa 2019. No entiendo por que en interactivo lo ejecuta perfecto y con el Programador de Tareas (Bach) da ese error y no siempre es en la misma línea de programación. Se me olvidaba el Excel tiene 70.000 líneas. Lo curioso es que hasta el 14-09-2023 funcionaba perfecto y sin haber modificado la programación ni nada en el ordenador a dejado de funcionar.

Gracias de antemano

He probado de todo, volver a instalar el Office, verificar la activación del office, modificar la programación de la generación del Excel, etc.